# monitor no hdmi signal

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, ubuntu

I've installed ubuntu classic server 16.04 (Rasberry Pi 3 edition) found here https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/ on Rasbperry Pi 3 b and everything is working as expected when I ssh into it.
I would like to use a desktop "stylish" setup for configuring the network and security settings.

After connecting the monitor and powering up the raspy this message shows up on the screen:

```
Net:    Net Initialization Skipped
No ethernet found.
USB0:    Core Release: 2.80a
scanning bus 0 for devices…
```

Could someone open up that message a little bit, what does it mean? I also get a little square icon with rainbow colors in the right upper corner

I have uncommented the the following lines in config.txt:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_safe=1 ← the last thing I tried
```

I've also tried config_hdmi_boost=9

I'm using a mobile charger with an output of 5 V and 2.1 A to power up the raspy, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient enough if you want the raspy to display an image on the monitor.

This site https://howtoraspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-hdmi-not-working/ recommended a charger with an output of 5 V and 3 A.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can't write this line in this way : 
`config_hdmi_boost=4 up to 9`
As the "up to" syntax don't seems to be valid in this case.

Instead, try to use `config_hdmi_boost=4` or `config_hdmi_boost=9`, or just leave this line as a comment :)